# Accessibility for button with font icon in it

Tags: html, accessibility, font-awesome

I'm having an accessibility problem with the button element. I'm wondering if this is the good way to do it. I have a button and the only content is a Font-Awesome (font-icon) in it. I was wondering if adding a `title` attribute to my button was enough to make it accessible ?

Like this:

```
<button class="prev" title="My accessible title">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use both `title`and `aria-label` attributes as some screenreaders does not read the `title` attribute, while other users won't benefit of the `aria-label` attribute.

You have to remember that accessibility does not only target screenreaders users but also every other people, so `aria-label` won't be sufficient.

Also note that, for better accessibility, you might want to add a way to show the description when you focus the button with the keyboard. That would be a good idea.

That being said, I will be silly enough to suggest that some part of the description of your button might be always visible for better accessibility.

For instance, the following examples shows how the two attributes might be used conjointly with a short visible hint for a popup close button :

```
<button aria-label="Back to the page" title="Close popup">
  <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  Close
</button>
```

Comment: in the case of a link with an icon (i.e. facebook), hidden by `aria-hidden=true`, should we add both the `title` attribute and a `span` with `sr-only` (by using bootstrap)? Screen-readers repeat both info, don't they?

Answer (score 6):

The correct property in this case should be `aria-label` or `aria-labeledby`:

```
<button class="prev" aria-label="My accessible title">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>
</button>
```

With this, the screen reader for example will reproduce `My accessible title` instead the icon inside it.

See more:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-label_attribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute

Comment: Should I combine both? or aria-label is enough?

Comment: `aria-label` is like the `title` you want to write. `aria-labeledby` is to make relations between elements. In this case only with `aria-label` I guess is fine.

Comment: Ok, so no title, only a aria-label (in this case since there is no relation with any other html element). That's it?

Comment: Yes, you can add a title for more versatility (normal desktop users), but the aria label is sufficient, and no, is not related with any html element. If you need to make a relation use `aria-labeledby` instead (I attach the two pages for make more knowledge to you). Can you accept / upvote this answer?

Comment: My upvote for your question too, this is the right way :) Glad to help you

Comment: But how a user who is able to see could know what does a button with icon stands for? I think that `title` attribute is required for buttons without text.

Comment: I agree, it's now 2024, and Chrome still doesn't show a tooltip for an element with `aria-label`, so setting only it is not good enough; setting `aria-label` and `title` is preferrable

Answer (score 0):

The `title` attribute is the most widely supported attribute for assistive technologies. This includes Dragon ([which heavily relies on the title attribute for targeting elements](http://www.nuance.com/ucmprod/groups/healthcare/documents/webasset/nd_004979.pdf)) as well as all modern screen readers that implement the [ARIA accessible name computation algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#textalternativecomputation) and many older screen readers.

As can be seen in step D of that algorithm, the final element that is evaluated is the title attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately all modern screen readers do not implement the ARIA accessible name computation algorithm and olders do not...